# Overwriting request methods in express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I was watching a video about middlewares in express and I saw the guy overwriting get request into post request. I got curious and tried overwriting get request to delete request on my existing piece of code.
My code is this:

```
app.use("/comments/:id/delete", (req, res, next) => {
  req.method = "DELETE";
  next();
});
app.delete("/comments/:id/delete", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  comments = comments.filter((c) => c.id !== id);
  res.redirect("/comments");
});
```

Note: I didn't followed REST because it was conflicting with show which I had defined earlier.

My EJS:

```
  <form action="/comments/<%= comment.id %>/delete">
              <button>Delete</button>
</form>
```

My ejs full image:
[image]

My server Detail Image:
[image]

Comment: And what is your question? Is there any error? :)

Comment: Yeah I am getting error. The middleware is not overwriting get into delete request.

Comment: @RosanPaudel Post your full code, perhaps your order of the routes is wrong.

Comment: why and how would expect the the overwriting to happen when you also have defined a DELETE request `app.delete("/comments/:id/delete"`?

Comment: Its working!!!!!!!

Comment: @chris app.delete is the route. It is not a request.

Comment: @eol The code is working. I don't know why it didn't worked. I just came from dinner and it is working flawlessy.

Comment: @Marc It is working now.